# Replaced drawable images in the custom listAdapter in android changes after scrolling the listview. Why?

Tags: scrollview, android-drawable, android-scrollview, custom-lists, shapedrawable

I use the CustomBaseAdapter to represent the list in the listView. The MainActivity is shown in the first image below in the link image which contains the custom listView adapter. And now when i click one of the items at the position number [4] the drawable images changes with filling the color as  in the image second. And again when i scroll the listView the filling drawble color disappered and remains the same as in the previous state. So how can i make this happen??

[Image Link to understand Clearly..](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-Tt6A6rVj1es/VdwXx6afIxI/AAAAAAAACPc/Mf8ROMaZfM0/s1600/all.jpg)

SingleRow.java

```
package androidhiveexample.jsonparsing.circularimageview;

import android.content.Context;

public class SingleRow {

    private String title , number ;
    private int image;
    Context context;

    public SingleRow(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }
    public SingleRow(int image , String title , String number){
        this.title = title;
        this.image = image;
        this.number = number;
    }

    public int getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(int image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
}
```

CustomListAdapter.java

```
package androidhiveexample.jsonparsing.circularimageview;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    ArrayList<SingleRow> rowArrayList;
    Context context;

    public CustomListAdapter(Context context , ArrayList<SingleRow> rowArrayList)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.rowArrayList = rowArrayList;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return rowArrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return rowArrayList.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return rowArrayList.indexOf(getItem(i));
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row_view , null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            holder.number = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewNumber);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        SingleRow singleRow = (SingleRow) getItem(position);

        holder.title.setText(singleRow.getTitle());
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(singleRow.getImage());
        holder.number.setText(singleRow.getNumber());


        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder
    {
        TextView title , number;
        ImageView imageView;
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package androidhiveexample.jsonparsing.circularimageview;

import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{
    ListView lv;
    String number[] = {"1" , "2" , "3" ,"4" , "5" };
    String title[] = {"Title_1_titlename" , "Title_1_titlename" , "Title_1_titlename" ,"Title_1_titlename" , "Title_1_titlename" };
    int icons[] = {R.drawable.one , R.drawable.two , R.drawable.three , R.drawable.four , R.drawable.five};
    ArrayList<SingleRow> singleRowArray = new ArrayList<>();
    SingleRow singleRow;
    static ImageView iv;
    CustomListAdapter customListAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        loopThroughRows();
        lv.addHeaderView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, null));
        customListAdapter = new CustomListAdapter(this , singleRowArray);
        lv.setAdapter(customListAdapter);

        ImageView iv1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewHeader);
        iv1.setImageResource(R.drawable.new_img);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                position = position - 1;
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                        // iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.one_background);
                        Log.i("IMAGEVIEW_ID", iv.toString());

                        Fragment_1 fr = new Fragment_1();
                        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
                        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fr);
                        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();

                        break;
                    case 1:

                        iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.two_background);

                        break;
                    case 2:

                        iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.three_background);

                        break;
                    case 3:

                        iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.four_background);

                        break;
                    case 4:

                        iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.five_background);


                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }
    public void loopThroughRows(){
        for(int i = 0 ; i < title.length ; i++){
            singleRow = new SingleRow(icons[i] , title[i] , number[i]);
            singleRowArray.add(singleRow);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            fm.popBackStack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

drawable/one.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thickness="5dp"
    android:useLevel="false"
    >

    <size
        android:height="50dp"
        android:width="50dp"/>

    <solid android:color="#64DD17" />

</shape>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG finally solved after 8 days of HANGUP. Thank for #AMD for helping me to solve this issue..

SingleRow.java

```
    private String title , number ;
    private int defaultImage ;
    private boolean isClicked;
    Context context;

    public SingleRow(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    public SingleRow(int defaultImage , String title , String number)
    {
        this.defaultImage = defaultImage;
        this.title = title;
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public int getDefaultImage() {
        return defaultImage;
    }

    public void setDefaultImage(int defaultImage) {
        this.defaultImage = defaultImage;
    }

    public boolean isClicked() {
        return isClicked;
    }

    public void setClicked(boolean isClicked) {
        this.isClicked = isClicked;
    }
```

CustomAdapter.java

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Log.i(TAG , "getView MethodofCustomListAdapter");
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row_view , null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewIcon);
            holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
            holder.number = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewNumber);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.title.setText(arrayList.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.number.setText(arrayList.get(position).getNumber());
        holder.icon.setImageResource(arrayList.get(position).getDefaultImage());


        if(arrayList.get(0).isClicked()) {
            if(position == 0) {
                holder.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.one_background);
            }
            Log.i("POSITION_CLICKED" , String.valueOf(position));
        }
        if(arrayList.get(1).isClicked()) {
            if(position == 1) {
                holder.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.two_background);
            }
            Log.i("POSITION_CLICKED" , String.valueOf(position));
        }
        if(arrayList.get(2).isClicked()) {
            if(position == 2) {
                holder.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.three_background);
            }
            Log.i("POSITION_CLICKED" , String.valueOf(position));
        }
        if(arrayList.get(3).isClicked()) {
            if(position == 3) {
                holder.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.four_background);
            }
            Log.i("POSITION_CLICKED" , String.valueOf(position));
        }
        if(arrayList.get(4).isClicked()) {
            if(position == 4) {
                holder.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.five_background);
            }
            Log.i("POSITION_CLICKED" , String.valueOf(position));
        }
        if(arrayList.get(5).isClicked()) {
            if(position == 5) {
                holder.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.one_background);
            }
            Log.i("POSITION_CLICKED" , String.valueOf(position));
        }
        if(arrayList.get(6).isClicked()) {
            if(position == 6) {
                holder.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.two_background);
            }
            Log.i("POSITION_CLICKED" , String.valueOf(position));
        }
        if(arrayList.get(7).isClicked()) {
            if(position == 7) {
                holder.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.three_background);
            }
            Log.i("POSITION_CLICKED" , String.valueOf(position));
        }
        if(arrayList.get(8).isClicked()) {
            if(position == 8) {
                holder.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.four_background);
            }
            Log.i("POSITION_CLICKED" , String.valueOf(position));
        }


        return convertView;
    }
```

MainActivity.java

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            Log.i(TAG , "onItemClickListener");
            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    arrayList.get(position).setClicked(true);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    arrayList.get(position).setClicked(true);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    arrayList.get(position).setClicked(true);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    arrayList.get(position).setClicked(true);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    arrayList.get(position).setClicked(true);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    arrayList.get(position).setClicked(true);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    arrayList.get(position).setClicked(true);
                    break;
                case 7:
                    arrayList.get(position).setClicked(true);
                    break;
                case 8:
                    arrayList.get(position).setClicked(true);
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
    customListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

Create or add that field in your model class for the staus of item in your list and then manipulate it in your getView . Like Below ..

```
public class StatusBean{

private boolean isActive;


public String isActive() {
    return isActive;
}
public void setNameActive(boolean isActive) {
    this.isActive=isActive;
}
```

}

And then set these fields to active state in when your button click. And call

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

and inside getview use if-else to change the image accordingly.
 let me know if you face any problem in it

Comment: Thanks for ur answer But sorry i don't get it. Would u mind elaborating it..

Please check this link to understand the question in better way:

http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-Tt6A6rVj1es/VdwXx6afIxI/AAAAAAAACPc/Mf8ROMaZfM0/s1600/all.jpg

Comment: When list scroll android System creates the new view .Thats why your state is lost when getView() is called again .For maintaining  it you have to do like this what i wrote above .get the color from image if isActive is true and fill it and in else part do nothing ...On your onClick on image setIsActive for this position as true . Then call notifydatasetChanged()

Comment: I don't get this line:  inside getview use if-else to change the image accordingly. WAITING FOR THE REPLY!!

Comment: First Tell me where are there rounded images are you creating these or they are in your drawable.

Comment: These Rounded circle are on the drawable folder..

one_background.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">

    <size
        android:height="50dp"
        android:width="50dp"/>

    <solid android:color="#64DD17" />
</shape>

Comment: Ok then create selector corrosponding to each rounded button of statePressed and normal state beacause you different color for each rounded button . and save these selector drawable in an ArrayList<Drawable> which will same size of your list view elements  and set these selector drwable to each of your listview rounded image Like --    holder.image.setBackgroundDrawable(YourArrayList.get(posintion));

Comment: Sorry but this way don't help me either. Would you mind to check out my codes above ??

Comment: In getview use if-else to change the image accordingly. I don't understand this line. Please help me #ADM, I'm waiting for the reply ..

Answer (score 0):

I have changed your model class.

```
public class SingleRow {

private String title , number ;
private int defaultImage;
private int enabledImage;
private boolean isClicked; 
Context context;

public SingleRow(Context context){
    this.context = context;
}
public SingleRow(int defaultImage , String title , String number){
    this.title = title;
    this.image = image;
     this.number = number;
 }

public void setIsClick(boolean bool){
this.isClicked=bool
}
public void isClick(){
return isClicked;
}
public int getdefaultImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setdefaultImage (int image) {
    this.defaultImage  = defaultImage ;
}

 public int getenabledImage() {
    return enabledImage;
}

public void setEnabledImage (int image) {
    this.enabledImage  = image;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getNumber() {
    return number;
}

public void setNumber(String number) {
    this.number = number;
}
```

And Then setIsClick to true and false in your onClickListener.Call NotifyDatasetChanged() .

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

ViewHolder holder = null;
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

if(convertView == null){
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row_view , null);
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    holder.number = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewNumber);
    convertView.setTag(holder);

}else{
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}

holder.title.setText(rowArrayList.get(position).getTitle());
holder.imageView.setImageResource(rowArrayList.get(position).getImage());
holder.number.setText(rowArrayList.get(position).getNumber());


if(rowArrayList.get(position).isClicked()) {
    holder.imageView.setImageResource(rowArrayList.get(position).getEnabledImage());
}

else{
    holder.imageView.setImageResource(rowArrayList.get(position).getdefaultImage());
}

return convertView;
```

}

Comment: Would you mind elaborating this line: << Then setIsClick to true and false in your onClickListener. >>

Comment: When your list item is clicked then do ..rowArrayList.get(position).setisClicked(true);                   and on 2nd click  rowArrayList.get(position).setisClicked(false);    and then call notifyDatasetchanged() on your adapter reference